# Prometheus query for table in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

When i make a table panel and go to "Options" tab, columns parameter set to Auto: Columns and their order are determined by the data query.

Is there a doc on how write prometheus queries for grafana tables?

My prometheus data is a metric with 2 labels `my_col` and `my_row`:

```
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="1",my_row="A"} 6
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="2",my_row="A"} 8
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="1",my_row="B"} 10
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="2",my_row="B"} 17
```

I want to make a table that looks like:

```
|   | 1 | 2 |
| A | 6 | 8 |
| B | 10| 17|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation in the Grafana docs about Table Panels here: https://grafana.com/docs/features/panels/table_panel/#table-panel

The particular transform you showed in the example doesn't appear to be supported in the above documentation unfortunately.

If possible, a change to the structure of the prometheus data to something like the below should make this easier:

```
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",col_1="6",col_2="8",my_row="A"}
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",col_1="10",col_2="17",my_row="B"}
```

Answer (score 7):

After some experimentations in **Grafana 9.1.1**, I have obtained a way to construct a table like you have described with prometheus metric like that. Here are Grafana **transform** functions you will need:

1. **Labels to fields**
   This function separate the labels in the metric to columns.

- Set **Mode** to **Columns**
- Set **Labels** to be only the columns that are relevant so in this case it's **my_col** and **my_row**
- Set **Value field name** to **my_col**

2. **Reduce**
   This function reduce all values in separate times into one row.

- Set **Mode** to **Reduce fields**
- Set **Calculations** to **Last***. You may change this part according to your needs.
- Set **include time** to **false**

3. **Merge**
   This function will merge all datasets into one with corresponding columns.
4. **Organize fields**
   Finally, this function will help you reorganize the table into something that's more proper. For presenting the data in bar chart, ensure that **my_row** column is the most left one.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with Grafana 7.0.3. I think it was possible with earlier versions as well, but the approach has changed since 7.0.0 with the introduction of transformations.

Add two queries:

```
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="1"}
my_metric{instance="lh",job="job",my_col="2"}
```

Make them instant queries and format them as tables. Create the transformation `Outer join` and join by `my_col`. You should get the two values as `Value #A` and `Value #B`. You can use the transformation `Organize fields` to rename them and drop all the other fields.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where you found that "Organize fields" option on the Explore view?

Comment: It's not available in the explorer, only on panels of a dashboard.